# How do to onblur/onfocus validation with jQuery/bootstrap without using any jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do to onblur/onfocus validation with jQuery/bootstrap without using any jquery plugin for the below bootstrap form. Most of the internet example has used with jquery plugin. I can't use any plugin for some reason.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="nam">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nam" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: May i know why the negative vote for this question?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. There are many many tutorials and books written on the subject of form validation in JavaScript and jQuery, not to mention HTML5, and not all of them use plugins. You've also dumped a bunch of code into your question which does not seem to have any relevance to the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

For each field you do something like:

```
$("#fieldId").blur(function(){
//your validation code, including showing messages and coloring the textbox with red.
});
```

And everything is wrapped in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```